# How to truncate MySQL table referenced by foreign keys

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to truncate a table in MySQL if it's referenced by a foreign key constraint?

I have two tables, A and B, and B.a_id references A. I want to `truncate table A;` but MySQL gives me the error:

```
truncate table A    Error Code: 1701. Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`mydatabase`.`B`, CONSTRAINT `a_id_refs_id_80cd2f13` FOREIGN KEY (`a_id`) REFERENCES `mydatabase`.`A` (`id`))
```

This implies that there are records in table B that are referencing records in table A. However, table B is completely empty.

I thought all I had to do was delete all FK references before truncating my table (which works as expected in PostgreSQL), but that doesn't seem to be the case in MySQL. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Drop the foreign key?

Comment: `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; TRUNCATE TABLE a; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;`

Comment: Comments are for follow-up questions, not answers :)